# createjs canvas repaint on scroll

Tags: css, animation, mobile, webkit, createjs

Using multiple createjs canvas stages on a web page.

Every time I scroll the page, on iOS Safari and Android Chrome, all the stages are cleared and repainted again (causing a long flicker).

Is there a way I can avoid the repaint on every scroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this. Is something resizing your canvas on scroll?

Resizing a canvas element will result in the canvas getting cleared. You can try doing a `state.update()` when the scroll happens.

Comment: Turns out safari is resizing window on every scroll because the navigation bar changes size. Is there no way to prevent stage clear on resize?

Comment: No. You can do a stage update, but otherwise try to prevent the resize. Mobile safari page resizes has definitely been a pain in many projects!